# How Fallback in CSS works

Tags: css, html, svg, png, background-image

I'm wondering how fallbacks work in CSS. For example:

```
 background-image: url("images/icons-page1/getq.png");
 background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");`
```

First image is given with location. Second image is provided with value of the `svg`. I think it's clear that the second one will be displayed if browser supports `svg`, otherwise the first one.

What I'm wondering is, the first one is loaded and then the second one also loaded, since the second one modifies value of `background-image` finally it persist. if second one is not working for some browsers, then first one persist.

In both cases browser tries to load both of their value right? Or only the last one is executed?

I'm asking for performance related answer.

Comment: [link](tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html) check this.

Comment: You could just try it using your browser's developer tools. (e.g. Firefox: `Ctrl + Shift + K` → Network)

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/

Comment: @kelunik I tested as you said I can't find the png file loaded so it means the first statement won't execute if second one works. when I comment the second one, I found png file in the console. thank you for your tip:)

Comment: Are you asking about how something works, or are you asking about the performance of something? You can't answer one with the other since they're two completely different questions.

Comment: @BoltClock performance is based on how something works. If the first statement loads the png and the second statement also computes the svg then the performance would be worst because only one is going to be used. so if it works in this way that is 2nd statement executed then you don't have to load the png, so the png loading time is cut down. I think performance is affected now.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no explicit statement about this in specifications, but actual browser behavior (which can be observed by monitoring the network traffic for simple test documents) is that a URL is processed and accessed only after the browser has decided, applying the cascade rules, that a property value with `url(...)` is actually used. Thus, if a rule contains two `background` declarations that are *syntactically valid* as per CSS syntax, only the latter is used.

In the example case, the first `background` declaration *never* has any effect. It would be a different matter if the second declaration were of different syntactic form, say a keyword like `dwim`, which might be defined in some CSS spec in the future. Then old browsers would ignore it and use the first declaration instead.

So there is no fallback. The browser decides, on the basis of syntax (parsing) and by the cascade, which declared value will be used for a property, such as a `url(...)` value for `background`. If it then turns out that URL does not work or yields an image in an unsupported format, the browser does *not* go back and try another declaration instead.